# How to call URL from Apache Camel in blueprint and return the data to a text file?

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel blueprints, my route is triggered from a URL at port 8081 on localhost. This route generates a file but the problem is the file is a binary file without the HTML showing.

I then navigate my browser to http://localhost:8081/foo which triggers the URL.

What is it that I don't understand that is causing it to output a binary file rather than a text file? I guess that I must transform the body somehow?

```
    <route id="url1">
        <from uri="netty4-http:http://0.0.0.0:8081/foo" />
        <to uri="http://www.google.com/?bridgeEndpoint=true" />
        <to uri="file:/test"/>
    </route>
```

---

Update: I think the problem is that the content coming back from www.google.com is gzip. When I look at the bridgeEndpoint parameter in the documentation it mentions something about gzip... now I am not sure, as I tried it on another website and it still doesn't work.

This line in my log might be relevant.

```
writing body: DefaultFullHttpResponse(decodeResult: success, 
version: HTTP/1.1, content: UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0))
```

---

Update: I discover if I do:

```
<from uri="timer:secondfoo?period=20s" />
```

Replacing the from, then it works. Hmm... Something flowing from the netty4-http causes problem.

---

Update: I found something which works! Obsession pays off.

```
    <route id="url1">
        <from uri="netty-http:http://0.0.0.0:8081/foo" />
        <removeHeaders pattern="*" />
        <setBody>
            <simple></simple>
        </setBody>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>GET</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="http://www.google.com/?bridgeEndpoint=true" />
        <to uri="file:/test"/>
    </route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the message to a `String` type then its text based

```
<route id="url1">
    <from uri="netty4-http:http://0.0.0.0:8081/foo" />
    <to uri="http://www.google.com/?bridgeEndpoint=true" />
    <convertBodyTo type="String"/>
    <to uri="file:/test"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test that soon. I love Apache Camel, but I hate it when I get stuck on something because when stuck, its sometimes hours. I need to start debugging what goes through, headers and body to understand it.